# Every interval in real numbers has a rational and irrational

Tags: calculus, analysis

How can you prove the following: where $a\not= b$, show every $[a,b]$ of R has a rational and irrational number.

The context for my question is as follows. In my intro calculus class, we were showing that the Dirichlet function is not integrable. This involved showing that the least upper bound of all upper estimates, U, and the greatest lower bound of all lower estimates, L, were not the same (on any partition of any interval.) This involved showing that L=0 because any subinterval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ contains both a rational and irrational, so $m_i=o$ and thus every lower estimate will be 0. But the fact that every subinterval has a rational and irrational member, though intuitively obvious, was merely stated.

Comment: The proof that the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ has been discussed here numerous times before, and is in just about any basic real analysis textbook (or Wikipedia). The second statement follows from the fact that the rationals are countable and any such interval is not.

Comment: Can you show that for any $\epsilon >0$ there's a rational number $p$ with $0<p<\epsilon $? That's an important intermediate step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a<b$ be real numbers.

Then we can see by dividing $\mathbb{R}$ into intervals of size ${1\over 2}\left(\left[{1\over b-a}\right]+1\right)^{-1}$ that some rational number with this denominator is in the interval, because they are equally spaced at the given length.

For irrational numbers, you can use cardinality arguments, since $(a,b)$ is uncountable, all the numbers within cannot be rational.

**Edit (addition): to leapfrog off of @user99680's answer:**

Let

$$a=\sum_{n=-N}^\infty {a_n\over 10^n}, b=\sum_{n=-N}^\infty {b_n\over 10^n}$$

with $0\le a_n,b_n\le 9$ as digits of the decimal expansion.

Then since $b>a$ we can find a smallest $n_0$ such that $b_{n_0}>a_{n_0}$. Then the number

$$a<\sum_{n=-N}^{n_0+1}a_n(10)^{-n}+10^{-n_0-1}<b$$

is a rational number between the two.

Similarly, we may use the fact that numbers are rational if and only if the decimal expansion is eventually periodic to show that if we write $\pi=3.c_1c_2\ldots$ where the $c_i$ are digits, that

$$a<\sum_{n=-N}^{n_0+1}a_n(10^{-n})+10^{-n_0-2}\sum_{m=1}^\infty c_m10^{-m}<b$$

is an irrational between them.

**Still further:**  we can see using ideas from Liouville's original proof that transcendental numbers exist to see that

$$a<\sum_{n=-N}^{N}a_n10^{-n}+\sum_{m=N}^\infty{1\over m!}<b$$ is transcendental so long as $N$ is sufficiently large, so choose $N$ so large that this is so and that $N>n_0$ and we get another one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use decimal expansions : let $a:=a.a_0a_1.... ; b:=b.b_0b_1....$ .To construct a Rational number  in-between , make sure it has a periodic expansion , to construct an irrational, in-between, make sure its decimal expansion is not periodic.  You can find a term a_j in the expansion of a so that you can repeat the string .a_1a_2....a_j as a period. Then, to construct an irrational , as Adam suggested, you can go far-enough in the expansion of a and append the digits o $\pi$ to it and get an irrational in-between a,b.

Comment: Why not make it explicit:  choose the smallest index where $b_i>a_i$ then truncate at the next step in $a$'s expansion and add 1 to the last digit. That gets the rational. Then for the irrational, just put the rest of the digits to be those from $\pi$.

Comment: @Adam Hughes: you're right, but I am using an on-screen keyboard, and it is difficult to write more than the basics.

Comment: I'll add it onto my answer:  it's worth taking a look at for such a neat alternative.

Comment: If $a < b$ are rational, $a + (b-a) / \sqrt{2}$ is irrational and strictly between both

Comment: @vonbrand : true , but we're trying a different approach, using decimal expansions.